# Placing two inline <div>s side by side in DTCoreText in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf-generation

I have used DTCoreText (through OCPDFGenerator) in objective C for converting HTML to PDF. Everything is working fine except placing two divs side by side. 

(I cannot use tables as DTCoreText does not support table rendering as of now -

 https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText/issues/144 )

EX:

> ```
> Left                                                                           Right
> ```

There seems no way to do so as no matter what attributes we pass in style , they always clutter together as internally it is merged as single text.

Code that I am using is -

```
<div style='float:left;position:relative;width:100%;'>
<span style='position:absolute;top:0;left:0;'>Left</span>
<span style='position:absolute;top:0;right:0;'>Right</span>
</div>
```

Output in rendered pdf file is (though html is correctly rendered on web page, float:left works too in similar way, so correctness of HTML is not a doubt) -

> LeftRight

This issue extends for maintaining many such pre-defined spaced text tabs side by side.

A workaround solution was to append spaces to first text string till it matches the passed width , but this gives an issue in case of multi-line text, so I could not go ahead with it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should create another `NSAttributedString` and place it where you want. It seems like DTCoreText doesn't support multiple column layouts so you have to do this using objective-c (not html).